# How to transfer nft from compromised wallet (sweeper bot actively looking) to secure address

Tags: ether, polygon, hack, sweeping

One of my accounts was compromised and I have a valuable lens profile nft in that... every time I deposit matic for the gas fee to transfer nft someone steeled immediately .....please help.....